# Is there anything like return a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a requirement where I get the anchor tags id and based on the id I determine which function to execute.. so is there anything that suites below code

```
function treeItemClickHandler(id)
{
 a=findDisplay(id);
 a();
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you simply check the id and perform a function based on that by using either `switch` or some `if else` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, functions are **first class objects** in JavaScript. For example, you can create a map (an object) which holds references to the functions you want to call:

```
var funcs = {
   'id1': function(){...},
   'id2': function(){...},
   ...
};

function treeItemClickHandler(id) {
    if(id in funcs) {
        funcs[id]();
    }
}
```

As functions are treated as any other value, you can also return them from another function:

```
function findDisplay(id) {
    // whatever logic here
    var func = function() {};

    return func;
}
```

Comment: @Felix: Depending on my code can you explain it, this is something totally new to me.. and mapping concept is something good here

Comment: @Abhishek: What do you want to have explained?

Comment: @Felix: So when FindDisplay  returns a, This a will be a function depending on the map.. where `a()` is replaced by whatever function `FindDisplay()` returns and can be called as usual?

Comment: @Abhishek: If I understand you correctly then yes, that's basically it. It's not so complicated. If you have a function, you can reference it by name and pass it around. Adding `()` after a function reference calls the function. And as demonstrated above, you don't necessarily need to call a function in order to get function, `funcs[id]` will also give you a function.

Comment: @Felix: Can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376161/what-or-which-plugin-in-jquery-shall-i-use-to-populate-a-html-table-with-a-xml-fi) please!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a function to a variable like so:
You can also return a function pointer from a function - see the return statement of findDisplay(id).

```
function treeItemClickHandler(id)
{
 var a= findDisplay;
 var other = a(id);
 other();
}

function findDisplay(id)
{
   return someOtherThing;
}

function someOtherThing()
{

}
```

Comment: I meant `findDisplay` returns a function, and that function is stored in a as another function

Answer (score 1):

functions are normal javascript values, so you can pass them around, (re)assign them to variables and use them as parameter values or return values for functions. Just use them ;) Your code is correct so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can map between ids and functions to call in a number of ways.

One of the simpler ones is to create an object mapping ids to functions, and find the function to call from that object (this is in essence a nicer-looking `switch` statement).

Example:

```
function treeItemClickHandler(id)
{
    var idMap = {
        "some-id": findDisplay,
        "another-id": doSomethingElse
    };

    if (!idMap.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        alert("Unknown id -- how to handle it?");
        return;
    }

    // Call the corresponding function, passing the id
    // This is necessary if multiple ids get handled by the same func
    (idMap[id])(id); 
}

function findDisplay(id)
{
    // ...
}

function doSomethingElse(id)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. every 1's answer helped me, yours too

Comment: Can you give me some solution for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376161/what-or-which-plugin-in-jquery-shall-i-use-to-populate-a-html-table-with-a-xml-fi)? Thanks