# What or which plugin in jquery shall i use to populate a html table with a xml file content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a requirement to display data from a xml file from server (path to file something like `files/client.xml`) into a html table or datagrid, which plugin or rather what should i use so that it has variable pagination, filter and table css customization. Any suggestions would help, a little example should be a plus point for me :) Thanks

**Note**: My xml structure is fixed

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="csmclientiir.xsl"?>
<csmclient product="abc"   date="4/26/11 2:05 PM">
<system>
    <osname>Linux
    </osname>
    <hostname>AbhishekNix
    </hostname>
    <release>2.6.18-128.el5
    </release>
    <filesystem>
        <file mount='/home/hp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/hp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/par21' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/par21)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/h231' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/h231)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/avallin1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/avallin1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/park' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/park)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/sp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/sp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/ganga1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/ganga1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
        <file mount='/home/nbp1' home='(innfs2:/vol/home/shome/home/nbp1)' total='1717567488' free='644306780' used='1073260708' percentage='62' />
    </filesystem>
</system>
<product>
    <showtime>Tue Apr 26 14:05:23 2011
    </showtime>
</product>
</csmclient>
```

**Updating with working solution**

Since it does not take attribute.. like here i'd like to get `mount`,`free` etc
Here is what i did in jqGrid for the above xml.

```
var i=0;
var filesystem=[];
$(xml).find('file').each(function(){ 
    var row={};
    row.id=i++;
    row.total=$(this).attr('total');
    row.free=$(this).attr('free');
    row.used=$(this).attr('used');
    row.percentage=$(this).attr('percentage');
    filesystem.push(row);
});


$('#detailTable').empty();
$('<div width="100%">')
.attr('id','diskUsageSpan')
.html('<div class="titleBlue">Configuration&gt;System&gt;Disk Usage</div>'+
        '<table id="list1" width="100%"></table>'+
        '<div id="gridpager"></div>'+
    '</div>')       
.appendTo('#detailTable');  



jQuery("#list1").jqGrid({
    datatype: "clientSide",
    height: 250,
    colNames:['id','Total Space','Free Space', 'Used Space', 'Used Percentage'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id',index:'id', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'total',index:'total', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'free',index:'free', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'used',index:'used', width:90, align:"right"},
        {name:'percentage',index:'percentage', width:120, align:"right"}
    ],
    pagination:true,
    pager : '#gridpager',
    rowNum:10,
    scrollOffset:0,
    height: 'auto',
    autowidth:true,
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    edit:false,
    add:false,
    del:false

});



for(var i=0;i<filesystem.length;i++)
    jQuery("#list1").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,filesystem[i]);

jQuery("#list1").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Works perfectly Thanks @Tomas and @doctrey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can read the XML DOM just as you read the HTML DOM, using jQuery selectors. So in your XML example, if you want to do something specific with each `<file>` element - say, add the contents of it's `mount` attribute to an unordered list, you could do something like this:

```
$(xml).('file').children().each(function() {
    var fileElem = this; // save the instance for closure
    $('ul#theList').append($('<li>').text(fileElem.attr('mount'));
});
```

You can get the XML contents with AJAX, using jQuery's built-in AJAX API:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "your.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
        // Insert the previous code snippet here
    }
});
```

I got all of this from [this tutorial](http://think2loud.com/reading-xml-with-jquery/), so it might be helpful for you too. Note: This was the very first hit on Google for "jquery xml"...

Comment: Thanks for replying. I looked at this tutorial before, and got quite good help, but I was hoping to find some jQuery plugin, that would make it easier and getting rid of the manual coding for variable pagination, filter and sort.

Comment: @Abhishek: You can probably make good use one of the plugins suggested in one of the other answers, if you parse your special xml format with this method and create data in the form the plugin requires...

Comment: now that is something impossible for me at such short time. Till monday I have to give something, bcz I require lot of examples and experiments. If you have some spare time, can you create data for `filesystem` in any of the plugin, only if you can spare some time. Please don't take it otherwise :)

Comment: I managed to make data for jqGrid and it works, for others reference i am putting it in my question. Thanks for guiding me

Answer (score 0):

[jquery.dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) is good as long as you have control over the contents of the xml file.  Their formatting requirements are rather strict.

Comment: my xml is fixed in their structure

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [XSLT](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/XSLT) - it will let you take the XML response and directly apply an XSL transform, which can then be inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Is there pagination, filter and css option in XSLT. coz XSLT is totally new for me? If yes, then any place where I can get a quick start

Comment: XSL can do selecting, for-each, sorting, and pretty much anything you could do with a read-only database :) Check out [w3schools' tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/)